# Correct way to insert elements with angular directive using angular.element()

Tags: angularjs

What is the correct way to insert element into the DOM using angular.element() ?

```
app.directive('validationTest', function(){
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                replace: false,                 
                link: function(scope, element, attrs){
                    scope.call = function(){
                        console.log('Someone clicked it');
                    };

                    var newElement = angular.element('<span ng-click="call()">').text('Yo Yo');
                    element.append(newElement);
                }
            };
        });
```

In this code, I am trying to add a span element within the element on which directive has been applied. I am able to add this span element as the child of the parent div on which append mehtod is called.

However, as you can see in the code, a `ng-click` also has been associated with this span. I know it is not useful from any point of view, it is just for demo purpose. So, normally, clicking on this span, a line should be printed in the console. However, it doesn't happen.

What am I missing here ? Have I used wrong approach for this append or there is some error in my code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the HTML that you dynamically append to the DOM has directives, then you'll want to $compile and link it before appending it to the DOM:

```
 var newElement = angular.element('<span ng-click="call()">').text('Yo Yo');
 $compile(newElement)(scope);
 element.append(newElement);
```

An alternative approach that is less error prone is to move your DOM manipulation to the compile function.  By inserting the new element during the compile phase, the new HTML will be automatically linked during the linking phase (no manual compile /link required):

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
     return  {
         compile: function(element, attr) {
              var newElement = angular.element('<span ng-click="call()">').text('Yo Yo');
              element.append(newElement);
              return function(scope, element, attr) {
              }
         }
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing angular compilation. The compilation traverses your DOM looking for directives and initializes them. Without calling compile, nothing will initialize your ngClick. Try this to use $compile:

```
app.directive('validationTest', ['$compile', function($compile){
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: false,                 
            link: function(scope, element, attrs){
                scope.call = function(){
                    console.log('Someone clicked it');
                };

                var newElement = angular.element('<span ng-click="call()">').text('Yo Yo');
                element.append(newElement);
                $compile(element)(scope);
            }
        };
    });
```

For further information: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use `templateUrl` or `template`.

View [$compile docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.18/docs/api/ng/service/%24compile#-template-).